# why the x dose not stay and how should i make it stay on the board

Tags: python

```
board = '''
3|4|7
2|5|8 
1|6|9
'''
loser = False
while not loser:
    user = input('letter  :   ')
    if user == '1':
        print(board. Replace)('1', 'x'))
    if user == '2':
        print(board. Replace('2', 'x'))
```

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game and the problem is that the x dose not stay on the board
Example:

```
letter : 1
3|4|7
2|5|8 
x|6|9

letter: 2
3|4|7
x|5|8 
1|6|9
```

Comment: Your code isn't valid python - please post your actual code.

Comment: Is this the actual code? `board. Replace` is not a function.

Comment: Also, assuming you're able to run your code, you're not actually changing `board`. You're simply `print`-ing it.

Comment: You could set board to the new value and then print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only printing a modified version of the board, but you don't save it to board again, also, directly use the `user` variable

```
while not loser:
    user = input('letter  :   ')
    board = board.replace(user, 'x')
    print(board)
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the replaced string and not updating board. To update it, write:
`board=board.replace("1","x")`

Comment: Thank you so much dude you made my day

Comment: I know you've accepted another answer but you can upvote my answer 